# function is not replaced with new one after button click

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me with the below?

When I click on the button generated with javascript, it does everything as per the function allocated to it, but it also leaves the innerHTML above it and the button "Play again!" as well.
Would like for it to generate everything as per function in the button, but without the innerHTML.
Hope my question is understandable.

HTML

```
    <div class="pic-guess-area">
        <div id="pic-area">
            <img id="pic" src="assets/images/hangmanGamePic0.png" alt="hangmanGamePic">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="play-area">
        <p>Guess the animal</p>
        <p id="word-input"></p>
        <div id="key-container"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="score-area">
        <div class="scores-div">
            <p class="scores">Wins <span id="win">0</span> </p>
            <p class="scores">Losses <span id="loss">0</span> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
var animals = ["dog","cat"]
let answer = "";
let guessed = [];
let animalStatus = null;
let wrongGuess = 0;

function randomAnimal() {
    answer = animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)];
}

function createKeys() {

const keyboard = document.querySelector("#key-container");
const keys = [
    "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
    "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",
    "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m"
];

keys.forEach(key => {
    const buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
    const insertLineBreak = ["p", "l"].indexOf(key) !== -1;
    buttonElement.textContent = key;
    buttonElement.setAttribute("id", key);
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => handleClick(key));
    keyboard.appendChild(buttonElement);

    if (insertLineBreak) {
        keyboard.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
});
}

function guessedAnimal() {
    animalStatus = answer.split("").map(letter => (guessed.indexOf(letter) >= 0 ? letter : " _ ")).join("");

    document.getElementById("word-input").innerHTML = animalStatus;
}

function gameWon() {
    if (animalStatus === answer) {
        let oldScore = parseInt(document.getElementById("win").innerText);
        document.getElementById("win").innerText = ++oldScore;
        document.getElementById("key-container").innerHTML = `Well done! That was correct!<br> <button id="reset" 
        onclick="resetGame()">Play again!</button>`;
    }
}

function gameLost() {
    if (wrongGuess === 6) {
        let oldScore = parseInt(document.getElementById("loss").innerText);
        document.getElementById("loss").innerText = ++oldScore;
        document.getElementById("key-container").innerHTML = `Unfortunately you ran out of possible guesses.<br>
        Correct answer was: ${answer}!<br><button id="reset" **onclick="resetGame()**">Play again!</button>`;
    }
}

function **resetGame()** {
    guessed = [];
    wrongGuess = 0;
    document.getElementById("pic").src = `assets/images/hangmanGamePic0.png`;
    randomAnimal();
    guessedAnimal();
    createKeys();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the innerHTML:

```js
function resetGame() {
    let guessed = [],
        wrongGuess = 0;
    document.querySelector('#pic').src = 'assets/images/hangmanGamePic0.png';
    document.querySelector('#key-container').innerHTML = '';
    randomAnimal();
    guessedAnimal();
    createKeys();
}
```

A few things to note:

- Markdown does not work in code blocks
- You should *always* declare variables using a variable keyword (e.g. `let` or `const`)
- While `document.getElementByID` works, `document.querySelector` is much more eloquent (and it has more flexibility and is consistent with CSS selectors).
- You should only use template strings where necessary.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This removes the button, but the text from innerHTML is still present.

Comment: @DarkoZlatarek My bad. I've corrected my answer.